# Swift 4: Are Strings reference counted & how to get that count

Tags: swift, string, performance, optimization, reference-counting

This performance optimization WWDC video suggests that strings are reference counted because they are on the heap.  This has implications on the performance of structs with Strings and whether something has changed in Swift 4 (now that Strings are collections again - with copy on write).  Curious how to prove this out and get an actual count.  `CFGetRetainCount` - doesn't work on Strings.

See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/

[image]

Using Swift 4.

Comment: Curiosity.  I've often created structs with Strings thinking there was little performance overhead.

Comment: Possibly.  Just want to understand what Apple is saying in the video.  Also wondering if what was stated in the video is now outdated with Swift 4.

Comment: I've been wondering this myself since I was also confused watching this video. I dug through the Swift source code and it looks all of the internal String types are structs that hold raw pointers, which would hint that it's stored on the heap. Not confident enough to post this as an answer though.

Comment: @matt Actually its not premature optimization, its a µOptimization. I added an answer with details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift Strings are value types which doesn't have reference counting. But the characters that string contains are kept in heap inside a reference type container storage, and that has reference count.

This is why Swift Strings has copy on write optimization -like other collections-

Using Strings -and also any other reference type- inside Structs is not a good idea for performance, because, on each assignment of Struct itself, all other reference types and String storage is retained.

When you have a value type that contains *N* reference type, on each assignment/deinit you need *N* retain/release. And you will have copy overhead for value types.

But if you define a reference type that contains *N* reference types, on each assignment/deinit you will have just *1* retain/release operation.

For exp:

```
struct Label {
    var text: String
    var font: UIFont
    func draw() { }
}

let label1 = Label(text: "Hi", font: font)
let label2 = label1
retain(label2.text._storage)
retain(label2.font)
// finished using label1
release(label1.text._storage)
release(label1.font)
// finished using label2
release(label2.text._storage)
release(label2.font)
```

If the `Label` was implemented as a class it would be

```
class Label {
        var text: String
        var font: UIFont
        func draw() { }
}

let label1 = Label(text: "Hi", font: font)
let label2 = label1
retain(label2)
// finished using label1
release(label1)
// finished using label2
release(label2)
```

On the other hand, this approach conflicts with struct's thread-safety offer. The same instances will be shared among all copies.

Since retain/release operations are on the heap and they have to be thread-safe, there is considerable cost for these operations.

So if you really need a great performance, including micro optimizations, and you want to **use value types wisely**, you should consider this approach.

PS: This approach is not changed by Swift 4, copy on write is another optimization. It creates a copy, only when value types that contains reference types with multiple references, are mutated.

Comment: Great overview. For those looking for even more of the details in a pretty easy-to-follow form, WWDC 2016 had a good session on this: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/